# Find nested arrays without aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My model is something like this:

```
Model    
{
     doc:[
          {  stuff1:{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Stuff1'},
             stuff2:Number
          }
         ]
}
```

is it correct to do:  `Model.findOne({doc:"some_id_of_stuff1"})`
My expectation is to get

```
                        {
                           stuff1:someData,
                           stuff2:data_related_to_stuff1
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Model.find({"doc.stuff1.type" : some_id_of_stuff1})
```